# How do I reinstall an app that was deleted but is still showing as installing?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, software-update

I had Google Maps installed on my iPhone.  Out of the blue it showed that it was "installing".  I deleted the app, but it still shows that it is being installed and the cloud symbol appears next to the app when I attempt to reinstall in App Store.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the phone?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with google maps however i think its just an issue with the iPhone because once i deleted the app and restarted the phone and then installed the app everything was working fine.